# I have three monitors, two of them mirror each other and the last is blank

Tags: fedora, graphics, multi-monitor

I have a triple monitor setup. I know all three monitors work and are plugged in. However on Fedora 23 my primary and secondary monitors mirror each other and my third monitor just on sleep and doesn't receive any signal.
I am using a Radeon R9 390 8GB GPU. Primary monitor is hdmi. Secondary and third monitors are using DVI.
Here is the output of xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      0.00* 
   1280x1024      0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00
```

Looking around the internet I found this command and it looks like its giving some good info? Not too sure.

```
[bowen@dehd ~]$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290] [1002:67b1] (rev 80)
    Subsystem: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Device [148c:2358]
    Kernel modules: radeon
[bowen@ehd ~]$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 hdmi
02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii HDMI Audio [1002:aac8]
    Subsystem: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Device [148c:aac8]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

I want to have three monitors with extended display but I do not know enough to accomplish this.

Comment: In your text you state all three monitors are working and in your title you ask (more or less) if it is unpowered. I pretty sure that if it is working, it has power. Please edit your posts so that it includes a real question in your post that asks something, and remove the question marks you tagged onto statements.

Comment: Oops sorry in my rush I had forgot to ask the real question.